# can't able to run app in iOS 7 build created from Xcode 7

Tags: ios, ios7, xcode7

I cant able to run app in iOS 7 build created from Xcode 7(swift), app installed in iPhone and its says "installing..." while clicking the app icon. Firstly I have develop app in Xcode 6.4 and its working in iOS 7 & iOS 8. after release of iOS 9 I converted code to Xcode 7, after converting app not working in iOS 7 but able run app in iOS 8 and above. How can I run app in iOS 7 any help?

Comment: Are you building with the correct profile?

Comment: It seems you do not have the correct singing identities. You are trying to deploy it to a iOS 7 device, not running it right?

Comment: Hi, I have add correct profile and Deployment Target is 7.0